# Scanning black & white line drawings

Tags: scanning

I want to scan an A3 BW 300 DPI fashion illustration line drawing to eventually render in Photoshop. However I want to draw the head 3 x larger using the same pen thickness to enable more fine detail.

I will therefore have 2 drawings at different scales that I want to scan and eventually merge into 1 in PS.

When I scan the head do I use 100 DPI so the line thickness matches the body @ 300 DPI?

Answer (score 3):

It would work, but you would have to take the thickness of the strokes into account. You would have to use a pen to draw the body that is 1/3 times the thickness of the pen that you would use to draw the head.

This is what I mean (and proof that I should never go into fashion design). Suppose you use the same pen to draw both sketches. You would end up with something like this:

[image]

Now, if you would use a pen to draw the body that is 1/3 the thickness of the pen you use to draw the head, then it would work.

[image]